# List of comma separated values in Excel cells to unique list of values and count

Tags: excel, formulas, vba

I have a list of countries separated by commas down 1 column.  I need to create a unique/distinct list of the countries and a count of how many times they appear as outlined in the picture.  Currently doing this via manual efforts and looking for a much quicker way.  Open to VBA but prefer formulas if possible.  Thanks!

[image: Example image]

Comment: why did you post this question here?

Comment: Record a macro of your search and find for one of the countries, and show us what you get.

Comment: https://excelxor.com/2014/09/30/list-of-unique-entries-from-column-of-space-separated-strings/ Shouldn't be too difficult for you to make the small adjustments from space-separated to comma-separated, though give me a shout if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following formula into cell `D2`:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&C2&"*")
```

This works by matching with wildcards. For example, the first search is on `*Bulgaria*`.

Note that if you have cases where a country name is contained in another, then you will count that too. (Not an issue for the example you posted.)

Comment: Thanks, msitt!  This gets me the counts. Still looking for a way to isolate a unique list of countries if I just have what is in column A.

Comment: You can use "Text to Columns" and "Remove Duplicates" in Excel to get the unique list of countries.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and expertise. I have tried text to columns and remove duplicates but not coming up with a unique list of countries. Text to columns leaves leading spaces and remove duplicates recognizes as separate values.

Comment: You can use TRIM() to remove the extra spaces.